# Populate a DropDownList using Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I need a very simple example of code to populate a DropDownList using Entity Framework 4.

At the moment I use this code:

```
        using (TestHierarchyEntities context = new TestHierarchyEntities())
        {
            uxSelectNodeDestinationDisplayer.DataSource = context.CmsCategories.ToList();
            uxSelectNodeDestinationDisplayer.DataBind();
        }
```

But it does not work properly... Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Have you set the DataTextField and DataValueField on the drop down list? When you say it hasn't worked properly, what do you mean; was there an exception, unexpected values in the drop down, nothing in the drop down??

Comment: Hi dave, thansk for your message. Could you post an example of code using DataTextField and DataValueField? Thanks

Comment: There's a full description of the control available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx but to keep it short and sweet, you should have something like: uxSelectNodeDestinationDisplayer.DataTextField = "Description"; uxSelectNodeDestinationDisplayer.DataValueField = "CategoryID";

obviously you'll need to subsitute in the correct field names from the entity you're binding to the control.

Comment: Hi, I tried your links but I am still not able to do it pro grammatically. I found a quick solution... at the moment I use Entity Data Source so I am able to bind the Drop Down Menu using EF. Thansk for now!

Answer (score 8):

Something like this should work :

```
using (TestHierarchyEntities context = new TestHierarchyEntities())
        {
                var category = (from c in context.context
                                select new { c.ID, c.Desc }).ToList();

                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "MID";
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "MDesc";
                DropDownList1.DataSource = category;
                DropDownList1.DataBind();                
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly:

```
private COFFEESHOPEntities1 CoffeeContext = new COFFEESHOPEntities1();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //getData();
        cbxCategory.DataSource = CoffeeContext.tblProductTypes.ToList();
        cbxCategory.DataTextField = "Description";
        cbxCategory.DataValueField = "ProductType";
        cbxCategory.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (dbEntities db = new dbEntities())
{
    ddlNewEmployee.DataSource = (from emp in db.CC_EMPLOYEE
                                    select new { emp.EmployeeID, emp.EmployeeCode }).ToList();

    ddlNewEmployee.DataTextField = "EmployeeCode";
    ddlNewEmployee.DataValueField = "EmployeeID";
    ddlNewEmployee.DataBind();
}
```